# How to change URL as SEO friendly?

Tags: magento-1.7, menu

menus of main store's urls are as follow.

```
http://mainstore.magento6.com/index.php/electronics.html
```

But menus of the child stores' urls are as follow.

```
http://store2.magento6.com/catalog/category/view/s/electronics/id/20/
```

I want to change the url of main store to

```
http://mainstore.magento6.com/electronics
```

I want to change the url of child stores to

```
http://store2.magento6.com/electronics
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Rebuild your catalog url rewrites.

Comment: Thank Marius. I did reindexing. everything are going well as your comment. But I didn't find to up-vote or do something. So I thank you from here.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly to remove the `index.php` from your shop's urls can be done by updating the system config found in the admin site under:

```
System->Configuration->Web->Search Engines Optimization
```

Here if you set the option `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `yes`

*Note: you may need to update the value of RewriteBase in your htaccess file to make this work*

The option to remove the .html suffex on product and category pages can also be set under the admin config.

```
System->Configuration->Catalog->Search Engines Optimization
```

Here you will find the fields Product and Category URL Suffix. If you empty these two fields, save the config and then refresh the `Catalog URL Rewrites` index then you should have category and product urls without the index.php and without the .html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to remove index.php from the URL and to do this follow following steps:

1. First of all, apache module ‘mod_rewrite‘ should be enabled. Check apache’s httpd.conf file this.
2. Then login to Magento admin panel and go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites and select ‘Yes’ from the selection list and save.

If your store is setup on sub-directory (example: http://example.com/store) then you have to edit htaccess file. In this file you have to remove # from #RewriteBase / and replace it with RewriteBase /store/ (store is sub-directory name).

If you want to remove .html from product and category urls then you have to follow following steps:

1. Go to System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engines Optimization
2. Empty product and category url suffix and save the configuration.
3. Go to System -> Index Management and reindex data.