# How can I get the correct product url based on store view?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url-rewrite, store-view, product-urls

I have 2 store view:

- `www.example.com` (EN Store)
- `www.example.it` (IT Store)

and I have 2 different urls that point at the same products:

- `www.example.com/car-honda-civic.html` (<--- I want obtain this url)
- `www.example.it/auto-honda-civic.html` (<--- and I want obtain this url)

and I use some php function to redirect the users to the right store based on user's language browser.

So, if I try to get product url (from my browser with italian language set) with:

`$product->getUrlInStore(array("_store" => "en"));` --> `http://www.example.com/auto-honda-civic.html?SID=2fdsfsd34fsdfsdf34$__store=en`

`$product->getUrlInStore(array("_store" => "it"));` --> `http://www.example.it/auto-honda-civic.html?SID=2fdsfsd34fsdfsdf34$__store=it`

How can I get both clean above urls product?

---

### --- EDIT ---

For completeness I add this:

I'm trying to get these links into a separate Magento folder:

`www.example.com/myproject/mypage.php`

and to load products I use:

```
require_once("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$grouped_collection = array();

// I need to get only grouped products
foreach($collection as $product) {
    if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {
      //echo $product->getId();  
      array_push($grouped_collection, $product->getId());
    }
}

// e.g.: load Product 12
$productId = $grouped_collection[12];

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$productLinkEn = $product->getUrlInStore(array("_store" => "en")); 
$productLinkIt = $product->getUrlInStore(array("_store" => "it")); 

echo $productLinkEn; //Output: http://www.example.com/auto-honda-civic.html?SID=2fdsfsd34fsdfsdf34$__store=en
echo $productLinkIt; //Output: http://www.example.it/auto-honda-civic.html?SID=2fdsfsd34fsdfsdf34$__store=it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using core_url_rewrite table in this way:

```
$productUrls = array();
$idPath = 'product/887';

$rewrite = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite');
$read = $rewrite->getReadConnection();

$select = $read->select()
    ->from($rewrite->getMainTable(), array('store_id', 'request_path'))
    ->where('id_path = ?', $idPath);
$data = $read->fetchPairs($select);

foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
    if (isset($data[$store->getId()])) {
        $baseUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, null);
        $productUrls[$store->getId()] = $baseUrl . $data[$store->getId()];
    }
}

echo $productUrls[0];
echo $productUrls[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are loading product then you just need to set store id in product object like below

```
   $store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView();
   // Gets the current store's id
   $this->_storeId = $store->getStoreId();
   $product->setStoreId($this->_storeId);
```

and then you can try with `echo $product->getProductUrl();`

Comment: Thank you but if set `$product->setStoreId()` I get url like this: http://www.mysite.it/mypage.php/catalog/product/view/id/80/s/auto-honda-civic/?SID=fsdfsdfsdf343&___store=admin

Comment: reindex your catalog_url. `System->Configuration->Web->Search Engines Optimization` set yes also refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8873/how-to-change-url-as-seo-friendly

Comment: "Search Engine Optimizaion" is already setting to "yes" and urls rewriting works great in all site.